# appropriate way to store users preferences for color selection, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, background-color

i was wondering what would be an appropriate way to store a user's color preferences. ie lets say the user is allowed to select the background color of a newsfeed based on the objects type. ie if it was an image, the bg would be blue, if it was a post, it would be orange etc.

how should a person go about doing that? im able to differentiate between all the different types in my views. i currently have a @feeds_item collection list and i render each object. then i have something along the lines of..

```
<% if feed_item.is_a? Post %>
    #render specific view
```

i was thinking in the view, of setting the color based on what the user selected. but how should i go about doing that? should i save the users color preferences in the User model, or in the Post model? Images model?

in my partial for Post objects, i have...

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">

  <%= link_to image_tag(feed_item.user.image_url(:thumb), :class => "image_avatar"), 
    feed_item.user %>

  <span class="user">
    <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
  </span>
  <span class="content"><%= wrap(feed_item.content) %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>

  <% if current_user == feed_item.user %>
    <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete, confirm: "You sure?", title: feed_item.content %>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

would i be doing something like the above except maybe change the < li > tag to something like...

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>" style="background-color=#{ ????? }">
```

where ???? would be a column in the db? is this a right way of going about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should save the preferences in the model where it belongs. If all preferences belong to the user, then save it in the User model.
2. The way to declare the style is:

   `<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>" style="background-color:<%= feed_item.user.this_color %>">`
3. Consider moving this to a view helper, so that your view can remain simple.

Comment: thanks = ) btw the syntax is wrong a bit. its style: "background-color...." as opposed to having an = symbol i think. thanks though! i shall follow the approach

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the syntax. It is now fixed. I had copied the incorrect syntax from your question!